# How stop systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd, startupscript

I am trying to create systemd service file for [Flume](https://flume.apache.org/), have created `/etc/systemd/system/flume-ng.service` with following contents

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Flume

[Service]
Environment=FLUME_CLASSPATH=/opt/flume/current/lib/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/flume-ng agent -c /etc/flume-ng/conf -f /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf --name a1 &

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which start the Flume service but how do I stop it as a service ?

In this case I had to kill with PID.

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to put in a `ExecStop` option in the `[Service]` section with the command you want to use to stop the service.

Something like:

```
[Service]
Environment=FLUME_CLASSPATH=/opt/flume/current/lib/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/flume-ng agent -c /etc/flume-ng/conf -f /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf --name a1 &
ExecStop=/usr/bin/flume-ng agent stop
```

or whatever the command is to stop the `flume-ng`

Then you can stop the service with `systemctl stop flume-ng`.

Read the manual at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html for the full set of options available to control the service.

Answer (score 34):

You can just execute `systemctl stop flume-ng.service`. When executed, the default action is sending `SIGTERM` to the main process and wait until a configurable time to see if the processes has been terminated. If the process doesn't terminate, then systemd sends `SIGKILL` signal which does the job. If the main process has forked off other processes, systemd will take them down too since they all live in the same cgroup.

You do not need to have `ExecStop=` directive unless you have a different way of shutting down your service.

Answer (score 0):

[ExecStop](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) is not sufficient in my opinion.
Also important is [KillSignal=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html). The signal that you use here should be the one that you would like to handle internally and safely exit the application.
Systemd would use the same  to kill your application. In case ExecStop= fails to exit the process, it will be killed by KillSignal. Last resort with systemd is to use SIGKILL and kill your process anyway to proceed with system shutdown.